# How to add animation on gif creation

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I want to add an animation to a GIF when I create it. I have created the GIF using this [library](https://github.com/mlapadula/GifEncoder), but I have no idea how to add animation images.

Comment: I suggest you : if you have a gif extract from gif sequence of image frames , than you will easy put animation frame by frame intro android project. With this procedure you can change in runtime you animation or speed of animation etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to glide lib for you.
You can add animation images.
It is very simple.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

https://opensource.googleblog.com/2014/09/glide-30-media-management-library-for.html